# Apagar arquivos criados antes de 10 dias atrás a partir da data atual

Tags: java, arquivo, data

Estou tentando automatizar a exclusão de alguns arquivos de backup que uma aplicação pequena que fiz em swing cria, que com o tempo, vai se acumulando, ocupando espaço demais no diretório de rede, que já tem um limite de armazenamento. A lista de arquivos fica nesta disposição:

[image: lista de arquivos com data de modificação]

Tentei fazer o método abaixo, e até conseguir obter a diferença de datas pegando a data de modificação fornecida pelo windows comparando com uma data informada manualmente, conforme código abaixo:

```
public class RemoveOldFilesDB {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //aqui eu pego de outro arquivo o link do diretorio,
            //está funcionando corretamente
            Propriedade prop = new Propriedade();
            File bkpPasta = new File(prop.getDatabaseURL() + prop.getDbBackupDir());

            File[] arqs = bkpPasta.listFiles();
            Date limit = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("10/06/2016");

            int contador = 0;

            for (File f : arqs) {
                //f.delete();
                Date lastModified = new Date(f.lastModified());
                if (lastModified.before(limit)) {
                    contador++;
                }
            }

            System.out.println(contador + " arquivos foram criados há mais de 10 dias atrás.");

        } catch (ParseException | IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

O código(fiz pra teste), conta o número de arquivos da lista  que foram criados no prazo, e me retorna corretamente:

> 9 arquivos foram criados há mais de 10 dias atrás.

Porém não estou sabendo como vou definir essa diferença de dias da data atual pra jogar no `limit`.

Como calcular essa diferença da data atual para que a exclusão seja feita somente nos arquivos que foram criados anteriores a data limite?

<sub>*Obs.: Não posso usar JodaTime porque a aplicação foi feita em cima do JDK7.*</sub>

Comment: `GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
gc.setTime(date);
gc.set(Calendar.DATE, gc.get(Calendar.DATE) - 10);
Date limit = gc.getTime().DATE;`

Comment: O que tem a ver JDK 7 com JodaTime?

Comment: @PabloAlmeida pra usar o jodatime no jdk 7 eu teria que adicionar lib a parte no classpath, e não posso fazer isso. Já no JDK 8 tem um equivalente(ou o mesmo, não sei afirmar) no pacote nativo java.time

Comment: Queria responder, mas não tenho como testar meu código hahaha +1

Comment: @renan quando der, posta ai sua sugestão, essas classes Date são uma dor de cabeça  pra manipular hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se é a melhor forma, mas eu uso o método abaixo:

```
public static void deletarArquivos(int qtdDias, String path) {
    Date data = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();//obtendo a instancia do Calender
    c.setTime(data);////setando a data atual
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, -qtdDias);//removendo a quantidade de dias
    data = c.getTime();//obtendo a data alterada

    File arquivos = new File(path);//instanciando o caminho dos arquivos
    String[] nomes = arquivos.list();
    for (String nome : nomes) {
        File temp = new File(arquivos.getPath(), nome);
        Date arquivo = new Date(temp.lastModified());
        if (arquivo.before(data)) {
            temp.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Funcionou como esperado, obrigado :)  Pra resposta ficar completa, pode adicionar estes comentarios direto no código?