# Apagar arquivos criados há mais de 10 dias, conservando o mais recente, se todos da lista tem mais de 10 dias de criação

Tags: java, loop, data

Eu fiz [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136067/28595) onde a dúvida era como apagar arquivos com mais de 10 dias de criação. Eu recupero eles de um diretório e o código já foi até implementado e está funcional.

Porém, acabei me deparando com um problema que pode fazer o código apagar todos os arquivos, caso o programa fique 10 dias sem ser executado. Eu preciso conservar o arquivo mais recente caso isso ocorra, mas como não sei em que ordem o java recupera essa lista do windows, não posso considerar que o último(ou o primeiro ad lista) seria o mais recente.

Como faço para conservar o arquivo mais recente, mantendo a estrutura de exclusão do código abaixo? De preferência usando ***recursos nativos do java***, pois tenho algumas limitações que podem me causar problemas se adicionar libs externas.

```
public static void removeOldFiles() {

    try {
        //resgato o limite de dias de um arquivo mas
        //estou trabalhando com diasLimite = 10
        Propriedade prop = new Propriedade();
        int diasLimite = Integer.valueOf(prop.getDbBackupDelLimit());
        if (diasLimite > 0) {

            Date data = new Date();
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(data);
            //seta a data limite de criação
            //dos backups antigos
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, - diasLimite);
            Date limit = c.getTime();
            //pego a URL da pasta
            File bkpPasta = new File(prop.getDatabaseURL() + prop.getDbBackupDir());
            //listo os arquivos contidos
            File[] arqs = bkpPasta.listFiles();

            for (File f : arqs) {
                //pego a data de ultima modificacao
                //para checar se tem mais de 10 dias 
                Date lastModified = new Date(f.lastModified());
                if (lastModified.before(limit)) {
                    f.delete();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

<sup>*Obs.: Infelizmente não posso usar recursos do java 8, porque a aplicação foi feita em cima do JDK7.*</sup>

Comment: Diego, não rola criar um POJO com o arquivo e a  data? Se sim você pode também criar  `Comparator` para esse POJO baseado na data, jogar tudo em uma estrutura de dados ordenada e pular o elemento mais recente (que conforme o `Comparator` vai estar na primeira ou ultima posição da lista).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly não queria aumentar a complexidade demais. Pensei em algum jeito de comparar os arquivos, salvando o mais recente numa variável temporária e apagando o mais antigo(semelhante a um ordenamento de vetor), mas não to conseguindo desenvolver a ideia no papel :/

Comment: Diego, realisticamente, você quer algo trivial, sem uso de bibliotecas e sem o Java 8 para resolver um problema complexo. É uma combinação difícil... De qualquer jeito você vai precisar de algum tipo de ordenação para saber se todos os arquivos estão abaixo do limite ou não, bem como comparar a data da última modificação. Enquanto você pode percorrer o array a primeira vez para descobrir qual é o arquivo mais recente e uma segunda para apagar todos os arquivos (potencialmente pulando o mais recente), isso vai acabar significando mais código do que o `Comparator`.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly por mim, eu usaria java 8(até porque a versão que está instalada na minha máquina é a 8) o problema é que essas limitações foram me impostas, e como é um programa simples e relativamente pequeno, não da pra argumentar esse tipo de mudança, todos que usam teriam que atualizar pro java 8 e o pessoal aqui, talvez  por ser publica, não gosta muito de "atualizações". Migrar pro 7 foi um custo. Mas você pode me dar um exemplo de como seria com o comparator?

Comment: Tenho uma resposta quase pronta usando um comparador, isso serve para si ou não?

Comment: @ramaral é nativo, serve sim

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depois de ter os arquivos num array:

- faça a sua ordenação por ordem decrescente da data de modificação
- verifique se a data de modificação do primeiro item tem mais de 10 dias

  - se sim, percorra o array, apartir do segundo item e elimine todos os arquivos.
  - se não, percorra o array e remova os arquivos com data de modificação superior a 10 dias.

Use este comparador

```
public class LastModifiedFileDescendingComparator implements Comparator<File>{

    @Override
    public int compare(File file1, File file2) {
        long result = file1.lastModified() - file2.lastModified();
        if (result < 0) {
            return 1;
        } else if (result > 0) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

assim:

```
Arrays.sort(array, new LastModifiedFileDescendingComparator());
```

O seu código, usando `Array.sort()` e melhor forma de calcular a data limite, ficará assim:

```
public static void removeOldFiles() {

    long daysToMilliseconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    //resgato o limite de dias de um arquivo mas
    //estou trabalhando com diasLimite = 10
    Propriedade prop = new Propriedade();
    int limiteDays = Integer.valueOf(prop.getDbBackupDelLimit());
    long limiteTime = new Date().getTime() - limitDays * daysToMilliseconds;

    File bkpPasta = new File(prop.getDatabaseURL() + prop.getDbBackupDir());
        //listo os arquivos contidos
    File[] arqs = bkpPasta.listFiles();

    if (limitDays > 0 && arqs.length > 0) {

        //Ordeno os arquivos 
        Arrays.sort(arqs, new LastModifiedFileDescendingComparator());

        //Se o arquivo mais recente estiver dentro do limite, apago a partir do segundo.
        if(shouldDeleteFile(arqs[0], limiteTime)){
            deleteOldFiles(arqs, 1, limiteTime);
        }else{//se não apago a partir do primeiro
            deleteOldFiles(arqs, 0, limiteTime);
        }
    }

}

private void deleteOldFiles(File[] files, int first, long limitTime){
    for (int i = first; i < files.length; i++) {
        if(shouldDeleteFile(files[i], limitTime)){
            files[i].delete();
        }
    }

}
private boolean shouldDeleteFile(File file, long limitTime){
    return file.lastModified() < limitTime;
}

public class LastModifiedFileDescendingComparator implements Comparator<File>{

    @Override
    public int compare(File file1, File file2) {
        long result = file1.lastModified() - file2.lastModified();
        if (result < 0) {
            return 1;
        } else if (result > 0) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Veja que, recorrendo a métodos auxiliares, o método principal ficou simples e fácil de ler.

Já que *removeOldFiles* é responsável por obter os arquivos a eliminar e sendo eles arquivos de *backup*, eu mudaria o seu nome para *removeOldBackupFiles*.

Comment: Não entendi como vou usar essa classe. No `Arrays.sort`?

Comment: Sim, editei a resposta.

Comment: Dá algum problema se eu usar através de classe anônima?

Comment: Não, já ela implementa uma interface(Comparator)

Comment: Valeu, deu certo, estou quebrando a cabeça agora para refatorar, o código que fiz usando sua dica funciona, mas to achando que escrevi mais do que realmente precisa pra fazer tão pouco.

Comment: Não acho que seja muito. No entanto, isso pode ser feito sem ordenar o array.

Comment: olha como ficou http://pastebin.com/m7UkZRts funciona, faz o que eu preciso, mas eu estou achando o código que eu fiz(logo após o arrays.sort) muito repetitivo.

Comment: Se tem código repetido extraia-o para um método. Passe aquele laço *for* para um método que receba o *array* e o primeiro índice a tratar.

Comment: Ficou bem mais organizado assim, separando responsabilidades. Mesmo se eu tivesse tentado, não teria feito algo perto disso, muito bom!

Comment: Só uma última dúvida, não entendi bem a utilidade da variavel `daysToMilliseconds`.

Comment: O valor retornado por `file.lastModified()` representa essa data em milissegundos(UNIX time). O uso de milissegundos evita a necessidade da conversão para Date e usar um Calendar para calcular a data limite, para depois fazer a comparação. A data actual, em milissegundos, é obtida através de `new Date().getTime()`. `daysToMilliseconds` representa um dia em milissegundos, é utilizado para converter o limite de dias em milissegundos na expressão `new Date().getTime() - limitDays * daysToMilliseconds`.

Comment: O resultado expressa o valor da data limite em milissegundos podendo, por isso, ser comparado directamente com `file.lastModified()`

Comment: Entendi agora. Não deu pra implementar hoje, amanhã vou adicionar na aplicação, desde já obrigado pela força :D

Answer (score 3):

Uma opção é ordenar a lista de arquivos utilizando o comparador:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.comparator.LastModifiedFileComparator;
```

A função abaixo ordena o array, ai você pode excluir a partir do segundo item.

```
File[] arqs = directory.listFiles();
Arrays.sort(arqs, LastModifiedFileComparator.LASTMODIFIED_COMPARATOR);
for (File file : arqs) {
    Date ultModificado = new Date(file.lastModified());        
}
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24159031/1997073

Comment: Vou ser sincero contigo, estou querendo evitar usar libs externas, uma solução nativa pra mim seria bem melhor, tenho alguma restrições aqui que, aumentando o tamanho do jar da aplicação, podem me resultar em problemas :/